# Catch Exception of overridden base class method

Tags: json-deserialization

I have an object of a class I want to serialize

```
class TimePOST {
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    private String startDateTime;
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    private String endDateTime;

    public String getStartDateTime() {
        return startDateTime;
    }

    public void setStartDateTime(String startDateTime) {
        this.startDateTime = startDateTime;
    }

    public String getEndDateTime() {
        return endDateTime;
    }

    public void setEndDateTime(String endDateTime) {
        this.endDateTime = endDateTime;
    }

}
```

Here's the actual serializer

```
class LocalDateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(String arg0, JsonGenerator arg1, SerializerProvider arg2)
            throws IOException, DateTimeParseException {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
        LocalDateTime returnDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(arg0, formatter);
        arg1.writeString(String.valueOf(returnDateTime));
    }

}
```

And this is the code where it fails to catch an exception thrown by overridden serialize method (DateTimeParseException)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testJSONSerialize", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Object getNewRORMSDetailsLocalTimePost() {

    try {
        TimePOST timePOST = new TimePOST();
        timePOST .setEndDateTime("2222");
        timePOST .setEndDateTime("2222as");
    } catch (DateTimeParseException exception) {
        //NO EXCEPTION IS CAUGHT HERE
        return exception.getMessage();
    } 


}
```

Comment: Please provide some information on the exception you need to catch. Why would you expect an exception from `serialize` to appear in that code block, where you don't even call that method?

Comment: @RolandWeber is right, your serialize wouldn't be called in the try {} part.

Comment: @RolandWeber serialize method is called every time you create an object of TimePOST class - fields are annotated using LocalDateTimeSerializer  class. @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    private String startDateTime;
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    private String endDateTime;

Comment: If creating an object calls a `serialize` method, the designer of that API had a really awkward sense of humor. That looks like Java code, and in Java, serialization refers to converting an object into a binary representation. There's no reason whatsoever why this should happen when you create an object or change its attributes. Have you put some debug output into the method, to check if it is really called? If it is, the logic that calls it might handle exceptions. Try throwing an Error instead of an Exception, that might get through.

Comment: Term "creating object" was used for explanation as the earlier question was "Where you don't even call that method".

Comment: In case debugger is used , it is invoked every time member variables of    
   TimePOST class  (startDateTime,endDateTime) is set.